# Navbar float cuts off header border-bottom (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a school project that has several limitations: CSS only (No JS) & a rigid delineation of sections. The idea is as follows:

```
top left header w/ image                                     top right navbar 
header border bottom covering width of page
```

I have successfully [pushed the navbar to its correct position at the top right of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riykO.png)

Unfortunately, this has cut off the border-bottom spanning the width of the page and no amount of jerking it around has allowed me to keep both.

Code:

```css
header {
 border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
 padding-top: 12px;
 position: absolute;
}

body {
 background-color: white;
}

nav {
 float:right;
 position: relative;
 text-align: right;
 list-style: none;
}

nav li {
 display: inline;
 padding: 10px;
}


#container {
 background-color: white; 
 width: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Final Project v2</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href=style.css />
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <a href=""><img src="img/logo.gif" alt="Logo"></a>
 </header>

 <nav role="navigation">
  <ul class="nav-main">
   <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="/">Books</a></li>
   <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>

 <div id="container">

 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

There must be something exceedingly obvious I'm missing and I'm losing my mind. Any suggestions?

Comment: i didn't understand the problem yet... Have you tried to use width: 100vw instead of 1200px?

Comment: [link](https://screencast.com/t/E195jsrq) without absolute/relative positioning, the nav bar doesn't stick to the top right. With it, the bottom border doesn't span the page. I'm trying to do both ideally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<header>` tag (with bottom border) needs to enclose **both** the logo **and** the nav.

It's more efficient to use the flexbox model than floats and to avoid using `position: absolute` where possible.

```
header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anandamasri/egju3w0q/2/) that will get you on track.

Answer (score 1):

Just Wrap the logo and nav on the header, and change the header to use flex.

Fixed code

```css
header {
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
  padding-top: 12px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
}

nav {
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
}

#container {
  background-color: white;
  width: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Final Project v2</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href=style.css />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <a href=""><img src="img/logo.gif" alt="Logo"></a>

    <nav role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav-main">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Books</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div id="container">

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can remove the style: nav {
  float: right; } since you're using flexbox.  Also nav { position: relative;
  text-align: right; } are unnecessary.